# How to open a .net project created using dotnet on the command line with visual studio?

Tags: .net, command-line-interface

I need to modify a project that a colleague created and then sent via email.
But I couldn't figure out how to open it with visual studio.

I tried to open the directory containing the project.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new project using command line, a project file is also created. The extension is based on the language selected. For example, it will have an extension `.csproj`. Just open this file using Visual Studio.

When opened, Visual Studio creates a solution file, with `.sln` extension automatically. When prompted, save it. A solution file is a structure for organizing projects in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

The project must contain a file with `.csproj` extension (given it's written in C#). Visual Studio is aware of it and will open it gladly unless something is broken on your machine, just double click it in your file explorer. `.sln` file is a solution file that contains references to project files (`.csproj`). It's not needed if all you have is a single `.csproj`, if Visual Studio prompts you to save it, you can ignore it.